# What should be the Arrayformula at D1 to get the column D?

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

[image]

Column A contains only unique value.

I have actually achieved this using two formulas:

(i) Arrayformula at B1:

```
={"ARRAYFORMULA 1";ARRAYFORMULA(if($A2:$A = "",,countifs(countifs($A2:$A, $A2:$A, row($A2:$A), "<=" & row($A2:$A)), 1, row($A2:$A), "<=" & row($A2:$A))))}
```

(ii) Formulas at column B:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B$1:B2,B$1:B2<>""), COUNTA(FILTER(B$1:B2,B$1:B2<>"")))
```

**(1) Why doesn't Arrayformula version of this formula doesn't work:**

```
=Arrayformula(INDEX(FILTER(B$1:B2,B$1:B2<>""), COUNTA(FILTER(B$1:B2,B$1:B2<>""))))
```

**(2) I am not able to get a single Arrayformula to produce my result. What Arrayformula should I use at D1 to my desired results?**

[Google Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DTYdN6keq6JBpiuPvTkZC7NPFFlTw8sA0RH3UpVma1I/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(COUNTIFS(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), 1, 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), 
 MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))-ROW(A2)+1, 0, 1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have edited the question. Can you please tell me the 1st part of the question too?

Comment: @AashitGarodia you mean: "Why doesn't Arrayformula version of this formula doesn't work" ? FILTER is not supported under ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: How do I know which all Formulas are supported under ARRAYFORMULA? Is there any documentation or article anything?

Comment: Also, your formula works even when I remove `ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)` which gives me this `=ARRAYFORMULA(SORTN(COUNTIFS(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A), 1, 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), 
 MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))-ROW(A2)+1, 0, 1, 1))` This is correct right?

Comment: @AashitGarodia if it works for you then it is correct. and ofc no, there is no list of supported formulas. its a trial and error

Comment: Thank you! Can you please help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73430607/please-help-me-understand-this-arrayformula